# Does a factorial always differ by a square from a square?

Tags: number-theory, factorial, square-numbers

Something I have noticed:

$$
4!+1=5^2\\
5!+1=11^2\\ 
6!+3^2=27^2\\
7!+1=71^2\\
8!+9^2=201^2
$$

And you can go on. What is going on?

Comment: There is nothing special. For any $n \ge 4$, we have $n! = 4m$ for some $m > 1$ and  

$$n! + \left(\frac{n!}{4} - 1\right)^2 = 4m + (m-1)^2 = (m+1)^2 = \left(\frac{n!}{4} + 1\right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.

**Additional hint:** Have a look at $2!$  or $3!$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We are claiming that

$$n!=a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$

then consider $n!=rs$ and let

- $a+b=r$
- $a-b=s$

Comment: sorry i can't get anywhere using this hint. Can you elucidate more?